# dont understand cron. What is 56 11 * * * /usr/sbin/update-file.sh

Tags: linux, unix, rhel

What does this command mean in cron? How often will this run? When will it run? Will it run daily?

```
56 11 * * * /usr/sbin/update-file.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

From [`crontab(5)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5):

```
field         allowed values
-----         --------------
minute        0-59
hour          0-23
day of month  1-31
month         1-12 (or names, see below)
day of week   0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

Thus, your line means to run `/usr/sbin/update-file.sh` every day at 11:56 AM.

Answer (score 2):

Crontab format is: minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week, command.

So this will run `/usr/sbin/update-file.sh` at 11:56 AM every day.

Comment: AM.. You mentioned the AM. Saved my entry. Thanks.

Comment: @user2081579: Don't forget that `cron` uses a 24-hour clock; 11:56 PM would be `56 23 * * * ...`